# Problemas com arquivo CSV (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Estou usando um código base de um canal, porém gostaria de retirar os dados trimestralmente, por isso alterei o link do código original, apenas, mas ao tentar rodar o programa tenho um problema, sou iniciante em python. Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado, não consegui entender bem o programa. Desde já agradeço.

Programa Original: https://gist.github.com/Vido/cbc33862dd27a22790df633f1d113ae6

```
import zipfile

def download():
    cvmzip_list = [
        'itr_cia_aberta_%d.zip' % y for y in range(2010, 2020)
    ]

    base_url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dados/CIA_ABERTA/DOC/ITR/DADOS/'

    for cvmzip in cvmzip_list:
        print('Arquivo:', cvmzip)
        response = requests.get(base_url + cvmzip)
        with open(cvmzip, 'wb') as fp:
            print('Download...')
            fp.write(response.content)

        with zipfile.ZipFile(cvmzip, 'r') as zip_ref:
            print('Unzip...')
            zip_ref.extractall()
            
download()

import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from dateutil import parser as du_parser


def carrega_dados():

    # Estrutura para carregar os dados
    # Empresa -> Categoria -> Ano do Exercício
    dados = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

    cvm_csv_list = [
        'itr_cia_aberta_con_%d.csv' % y for y in range(2010, 2020)
    ]

    for cvm_csv in cvm_csv_list:
        
        print('Processando:', cvm_csv)
        with open(cvm_csv, encoding='iso-8859-1') as fp:

            next(fp) # Pula o header
            csv_reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';')

            for row in csv_reader:
                empresa = row[3]
                ref = (du_parser.parse(row[9]), du_parser.parse(row[10]))
                categoria = (row[11], row[12])
                valor = float(row[13])

                dados[empresa][categoria][ref] = valor

    return dados

dados = carrega_dados()

import pandas as pd

tabela=pd.DataFrame(dados)
print(tabela.columns.values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, vamos lá
Analisando o csv que você escolheu, esse nome que você buscou na sua base, ele não existe. Dessa maneira, eu modifiquei o código com o nome do csv descompactado "itr_cia_aberta_%d". Como também, alterei o número de colunas para você reaproveitar o código. Pois se você olhar, verá que o csv dre tem número de colunas diferentes do itr .

```
import zipfile
import requests

def download():
    cvmzip_list = [
        'itr_cia_aberta_%d.zip' % y for y in range(2010, 2020)
    ]

    base_url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dados/CIA_ABERTA/DOC/ITR/DADOS/'

    for cvmzip in cvmzip_list:
        print('Arquivo:', cvmzip)
        response = requests.get(base_url + cvmzip)
        with open(cvmzip, 'wb') as fp:
            print('Download...')
            fp.write(response.content)

        with zipfile.ZipFile(cvmzip, 'r') as zip_ref:
            print('Unzip...')
            zip_ref.extractall()


download()

import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from dateutil import parser as du_parser




def carrega_dados():
    # Estrutura para carregar os dados
    # Empresa -> Categoria -> Ano do Exercício
    dados = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

    cvm_csv_list = [
        'itr_cia_aberta_%d.csv' % y for y in range(2010, 2020)
    ]

    print(cvm_csv_list)

    for cvm_csv in cvm_csv_list:

        print('Processando:', cvm_csv)
        with open(cvm_csv, encoding='iso-8859-1') as fp:

            next(fp)  # Pula o header
            csv_reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=';')

            for row in csv_reader:
                empresa = row[3]
                ref = (du_parser.parse(row[1]), du_parser.parse(row[7]))
                categoria = (row[5])
                valor = float(row[6])

                dados[empresa][categoria][ref] = valor

    return dados


dados = carrega_dados()

import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.DataFrame(dados)
print(tabela.columns.values)
```